# app.get(name) vs app.get(path, [callback...], callback) in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Express, from the API docs it seems we have two `app.get()` methods one to get the value of a variable, the other most of us are familiar with to handle http GET requests.

What is the difference between these two? How does Express know which one we want? Are they actually the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same function. `express` decides what to do based on the invocation.

The code for `get()` starts with:

```
if (1 == arguments.length) ...
```

If it matches the `get(name)` signature, it returns a previously `set()` value; if it matches the route signature, it binds a path to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Express checks for number of arguments. `1 == arguments.length`
If it is 1 then it knows it is for getting the value.

Actually set() is overridden for get() as well in a similar fashion.